# Rails: Strong params are missing on API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postman

I'm trying to create app with Rails as an API provider and stuck a bit during seting my user authentication process. Whenever I try to create a new user by Postman I get a message that my controller cannot recognize user params and rise an error:

> Started POST "/api/v1/create" for ::1 at 2020-02-23 02:36:29 +0100
>   Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as */*   Parameters:
>   {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "username"=>"Andrzej Strzelba", "email"=>"andrzej@strzelba.com"}
>   {"password"=>"qwertyUI1", "password_confirmation"=>"qwertyUI1",
>   "username"=>"Andrzej Strzelba", "email"=>"andrzej@strzelba.com",
>   "controller"=>"api/v1/users", "action"=>"create"} Completed 400 Bad
>   Request in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value
>   is empty: user):    app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:28:in
>   `user_params' app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:8:in`create'

and my controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def create
        puts params
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            render json: { status: :created, user: @user}
        else
            render json: {status: 500, errors: @user.errors.full_messages }
        end
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end 

    end
```

I am almost sure that problem is caused by a lack of wrapping my params with "user" key. I mean user: {email: '...', username: '...' ect} but I am not excactly sure how to solve it on Postman. I tried to send below JSON as well. But it did not succed as well:

```
{
    "user":
    {
        "username": "Andrzej Strzelba",
        "email": "andrzej@strzelba.com",
        "passowrd": "qwertyUI1!",
        "password_confirmation": "qwertyUI1!"
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good. First, let assume you were using postman incorrectly. Have you tried this?

Below url, you can find:  Body >> raw >> JSON (look at the picture)

[postman body send json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlTtv.png)

Else, you can try to remove the `require(:user)`, so it becomes:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

And send the JSON:

```
{
    "username": "Andrzej Strzelba",
    "email": "andrzej@strzelba.com",
    "passowrd": "qwertyUI1!",
    "password_confirmation": "qwertyUI1!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing your params as an user object, send it without the user keyword. Like this

```
{
        "username": "Andrzej Strzelba",
        "email": "andrzej@strzelba.com",
        "passowrd": "qwertyUI1!",
        "password_confirmation": "qwertyUI1!"
}
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try Posting your users params like this and Add access token in authorization.

```
{
    "username": "Andrzej Strzelba",
    "email": "andrzej@strzelba.com",
    "passowrd": "qwertyUI1!",
    "password_confirmation": "qwertyUI1!"
}
```